# Unable to connect to POSTGRES and showing error

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a problem to connect server for Postgres after I installed it. When I try to `psql -U postgres -h localhost` it show this error:

> psql: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
> connection to server at "localhost" (127.0.0.1), port 5432 failed: Connection refused (0x0000274D/10061)
> Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

I have tried start/restart the postgresql-X64 service but it still show the error.

Comment: So, is your service configured to listen on localhost and on port 5432?

Comment: how do I configure that? @a_horse_with_no_name